# Weird undefined symbol error

Tags: c, compilation

I have set the following h file: 
[image: h file code with error]

I have no clue why i get the error regarding my c file.
here is the only place in my c file which i use this function:

```
Inc1(int ptr)
{
  set_sist(print_var1);
  while (1)
  {
     count1++;
     if ((count1 % 20000) == 0)
       var1++;
  } // while

}  /* Inc */
```

needless to say that i have a `#include "my1.h"` in the head of the file.
the error is: **Undefined symbol _set_sist in module hw4.c**

the function is being implemented in another c file :

```
#include <conf.h>
#include <kernel.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <proc.h>   // for currpid
#include "my1.h"    // uses 'FPTR' type


SYSCALL set_sist(FPTR int1)
{   
bla bla bla bla
}
```

i compile the files using bat file with the following code:

```
    e:
cd xinu4win\newsrc\hw4
path e:\tc\tc\bin;%path%
tcc -I.. -c -DTURBOC initiali.c 

tcc -I.. -c initiali.c > errs
tcc -I.. -c kill.c > errs
tcc -I.. -c resched.c > errs 
tcc -I.. -c setsist.c > errs

type errs


tlib xinu.lib -+ initiali.obj -+ kill.obj -+ resched.obj -+setsist.obj
tlib xinu.lib -+ setsist.obj
tcc -I.. hw4.c my1.h ..\xinu.lib 
hw4
pause
```

any idea?

Comment: could you post the build log? i can barely read it from that image.

Comment: Link the object file containing the **definition** of the `set_sist()` function together with the other files. Including the header file ain't enough.

Comment: stop posting images as they are badly readible.

Comment: I have to ask - Why are you using a 21-year-old compiler?

Comment: because the task is on a very old system and we are forced to use a 21 years old compiler....

Comment: Microsoft lets you download free versions of Visual Studio, the Express editions.  It's not "fully featured," but It's been enough for me on Windows and should be enough for any student or hobbyist.

Comment: Please excuse the ignorant question, but are you sure `setsist.c` implements `set_sist()` and not `setsist()`?

Comment: alk, yes the name of the file is setsist.c but it implements set_sist(...) look at my edit..

Comment: Err ... It had really been too long since I used TC to be sure, but shouldn't the external declaration be `extern SYSCALL set_sist(FPTR);`?

Answer (score 0):

The linker searches your code and all the libraries for references. Perhaps you did not include a needed library or other object module?

Comment: i presented the completion command.. can you find something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference of an underscore.  Is that something your compiler appends to the front of all symbols in its processing or are you using both `set_sist` and `_set_sist` as functions?

I see where you are using it, in `Inc1`, and that you claim that it exists by `extern int set_sist(int)`, but where do you define it?  If you don't define it, it will compile fine, because your extern statement promised the function existed somewhere else, but it won't link when the linker really needs the definition.

Comment: I do not use _set_sist . the function is implemented in another file its signture is: SYSCALL set_sist(FPTR int1)

Comment: That other file needs to be compiled and then linked with this one.  It looks like you're linking it into xinu.lib.  I don't know your compiler's syntax, but I'm not sure you're actually linking in xinu.lib when you list it on the command-line like that.  Try using -l in front of your library file to specify the pre-compiled library.

Comment: Xinu is a given system. my task is to change it. so i'd like to add 2 more c files and 1 header file into the Xinu lib... i doubt there is a problem with the order of compilation commands.. it always worked before.